# Operator Overload With Pointers

Tags: c++, pointers, operator-overloading

As a part of our exam review package for next week, we are asked to understand pointers in overloaded operators-- something I am finding it very difficult to get and the instructor is refusing to give us any example, and asking his for independent study.

Apparently we will be having one of these problems on the final and I want to be sure I properly understand this practice exercise.

This practice concerns the issue of operator overloading. And we are asked to implement << and >>. 
And we are to :

> Using the FlashDrive class you have been working with, upgrade the class so
>   that operator << and operator >> work well with pointers (that is,
>   FlashDrive *). Youll need to re-overload these operators, adding the
>   function:
>
> friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const FlashDrive * drive );
>
> friend std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, FlashDrive * & drive );
>
> HINT: Be very careful to test for NULL
>
> NOTE: These ideas will be a part on next weeks assignment!

The code I am working with is

**FlashDrive.h**

```
#ifndef FLASHDRIVE_H
#define FLASHDRIVE_H

class FlashDrive {
public:
FlashDrive( );
FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn );
void plugIn( );
void pullOut( );
void writeData( int amount );
void eraseData( int amount );
void formatDrive( );

int getCapacity( );
void setCapacity( int amount );

int getUsed( );
void setUsed( int amount );

bool isPluggedIn( );
private:
int my_StorageCapacity; 
int my_StorageUsed; 
bool my_IsPluggedIn;

}





#endif
```

**FlashDriver.cpp --- Driver Class**

```
#include <iostream>
#include "FlashDrive.h"
using namespace cs52;

void main( )
{

cs52::FlashDrive empty;
cs52::FlashDrive drive1( 10, 0, false );
cs52::FlashDrive drive2( 20, 0, false );

drive1.plugIn( );
drive1.formatDrive( );
drive1.writeData( 5 );
drive1.pullOut( );

drive2.plugIn( );
drive2.formatDrive( );
drive2.writeData( 1 );
drive2.pullOut( );

// read in a FlashDrive... 
// the class designer for FlashDrive (that's you!)
// gets to decide which fields matter and should be read in
cs52::FlashDrive sample;
cin >> sample;

// print out a FlashDrive...
// the class designer for FlashDrive (that's you!)
// gets to decide which fields matter and should be printed
cout << sample << endl;

cs52::FlashDrive combined = drive1 + drive2;
cout << "this drive's filled to " << combined.getUsed( ) << endl;

cs52::FlashDrive other = combined – drive1;
cout << "the other cup's filled to " << other.getUsed( ) << endl;

if (combined > other) {
  cout << "looks like combined is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}

if (drive2 > other) {
  cout << "looks like drive2 is bigger..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like other is bigger..." << endl;
}

if (drive2 < drive1) {
  cout << "looks like drive2 is smaller..." << endl;
}
else {
  cout << "looks like drive1 is smaller..." << endl;
}

// let's throw some exceptions...

try {
  empty = empty – combined;
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}

try {
  drive2.writeData( 10000 );
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}

try {
  cs52::FlashDrive f( -1, -1, false );
  cout << "something not right here..." << endl;
} catch( std::logic_error ) {
// an exception should get thrown... 
// so the lines of code here should
// be run, not the cout statement...
}

// work with the new stuff added for Unit 16!!!

cs52::FlashDrive * drive3 = NULL;
// careful...
cout << drive3 << endl;

drive3 = &drive2;
cout << drive3 << endl;

drive3 = new FlashDrive();
cin  >> drive3;
cout << drive3 << endl;

delete( drive3 );

}
```

I would like to see what a working implementation class would look like so I can reverse engineer that and use that as a study source. I am finding getting some of these pointers to work very challenging

The implementation class I have already coded is below

**FlashDrive.cpp**

```
#include "FlashDrive.h"


FlashDrive::FlashDrive( ) {
  my_StorageCapacity = 0;
  my_StorageUsed = 0;
  my_IsPluggedIn = false;
}


FlashDrive::FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn ) { 
  my_StorageCapacity = capacity;
  my_StorageUsed = used;
  my_IsPluggedIn = pluggedIn;
}

void FlashDrive::plugIn( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = true;
}

void FlashDrive::pullOut( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = false;
}

void FlashDrive::writeData( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed += amount;
}

void FlashDrive::eraseData( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed -= amount;
}

void FlashDrive::formatDrive( ) {
  my_StorageUsed = 0;
}


int  FlashDrive::getCapacity( ) {
  return( my_StorageCapacity );
}

void FlashDrive::setCapacity( int amount ) {
  my_StorageCapacity = amount;
}

int  FlashDrive::getUsed( ) {
  return( my_StorageUsed );
}

void FlashDrive::setUsed( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed = amount;
}

bool FlashDrive::isPluggedIn( ) {
  return( my_IsPluggedIn );
}
```

**EDIT::::::**

I have updated the .h and .cpp
but I am still unable to properly add the << and >> operators :-( 
Any ideas??

**.h**

```
 #ifndef FLASHDRIVE_H
#define FLASHDRIVE_H
namespace cs52
{
class FlashDrive {

friend FlashDrive operator+ (FlashDrive used1 , FlashDrive used2);
friend FlashDrive operator- (FlashDrive used3, FlashDrive used4 );

public:
    friend std::ostream& operator <<( std::ostream& outs, const FlashDrive * drive );
    friend std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, FlashDrive * & drive );
    FlashDrive& FlashDrive::operator=(int);
    FlashDrive::FlashDrive(int);
    FlashDrive(const std::string &name): name_(name){
    }
    FlashDrive& operator = (const FlashDrive& usedtotal){
        my_StorageUsed= usedtotal.my_StorageUsed;
        return *this;
}
FlashDrive( );
FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn );
void plugIn( );
void pullOut( );
void writeData( int amount );
void eraseData( int amount );
void formatDrive( );

int getCapacity( );
void setCapacity( int amount );

int getUsed( );
void setUsed( int amount );

bool isPluggedIn( );
private:
int my_StorageCapacity; 
std::string   name_;
int my_StorageUsed; 
bool my_IsPluggedIn;

    }extern drive1,drive2;



inline FlashDrive operator+ (FlashDrive used1, FlashDrive used2 ) {

    FlashDrive plus;
    plus.my_StorageUsed = (used1.getUsed()+ used2.getUsed());
    return plus;
}

inline bool operator< (FlashDrive &lhs,FlashDrive &rhs ) {
   return ( lhs.getUsed() < rhs.getUsed() );
}

inline bool operator> (FlashDrive &lhs,FlashDrive &rhs ) {
   return ( operator <( rhs, lhs ) );
}

inline FlashDrive operator - (FlashDrive used3, FlashDrive used4 ){
    FlashDrive minus;
    minus.my_StorageUsed = (used3.getUsed()- used4.getUsed());
    return minus;

    }


#endif
```

**.cpp**

```
    #include <cstdlib>
#include <iostream>
#include "FlashDrive.h"
using namespace cs52;
using namespace std;

std::ostream& operator <<(std::ostream& outs, const FlashDrive * drive )
{
   outs << drive->name_;
   return outs;
}

std::istream& operator >>( std::istream& ins, FlashDrive * & drive )
{
    ins >> drive->name_;
    return ins;
}

FlashDrive::FlashDrive( ) {
 my_StorageCapacity = 0;
 my_StorageUsed = 0;
 my_IsPluggedIn = false;
}

FlashDrive::FlashDrive( int capacity, int used, bool pluggedIn ) { 
  my_StorageCapacity = capacity;
  my_StorageUsed = used;
  my_IsPluggedIn = pluggedIn;
}

void FlashDrive::plugIn( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = true;
}

void FlashDrive::pullOut( ) {
  my_IsPluggedIn = false;

}
void FlashDrive::writeData( int amount ) {
 my_StorageUsed += amount;
}
void FlashDrive::eraseData( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed -= amount;
}
void FlashDrive::formatDrive( ) {
  my_StorageUsed = 0;
}
int  FlashDrive::getCapacity( ) {
  return( my_StorageCapacity );
}
void FlashDrive::setCapacity( int amount ) {
  my_StorageCapacity = amount;
}
int  FlashDrive::getUsed( ) {
  return( my_StorageUsed );
}
void FlashDrive::setUsed( int amount ) {
  my_StorageUsed = amount;
}
bool FlashDrive::isPluggedIn( ) {
  return( my_IsPluggedIn );
}
```

Comment: Please don't tell me you were *taught* to use `void main`.

Comment: @chris He gives this all the time in his lectures, so-- in some ways, yes I Guess I was... :-/ 

I appreciate you bringing this up, I don't want to form bad habits now...

Comment: And your istructor is asking you to test for "`NULL`" in C++?

Comment: Kindly direct your instructor to § 3.6.1/2.

Comment: You also need to close class definitions with ;

Comment: @bash.d Yes, in addition to upgrading the class so that upgrade the class so that operator << and operator >> work well with pointers (FlashDrive *). ---

Comment: @rezivor I was hinting, that there is no "`NULL`"-macro in C++, you should use `0`, instead.
What are your achievements so far? There are many examples on the web about overloading `<<` and `>>`. Google for `operator<<` or `operator>>`

Comment: @bash.d, There is in `<cstdlib>`, but `nullptr` is the preferred value to compare to.

Comment: As of C++11, yes, that is true!

Comment: Have you been shown any operator overloading? I suggest that you build it step by step. First find out how to overload any operator, say `+`, *inside the class*. Then find out how to make it a friend. Then use that knowledge to build `<<`, passing a `FlashDrive` reference. Finally, convert that to use a pointer.

Comment: I can't for the life of me figure out how inputting or outputting a pointer to your class is useful in any way.

Comment: @chris I believe he wants to be able to do: `FlashDrive *ptr = new FlashDrive(); std::cout << ptr;` instead of `FlashDrive d; std::cout << d;`

Comment: I see neither pointers nor overloaded operators in your example, why the title you've given to the question?

Comment: @Xaqq, Which is useless and wasteful, really, and will need a lot of calls before the extra asterisk each time catches up to the character count of the overload, and it will never be apparent to the user what it does.

Comment: @chris While I don't think the length of the code really matter here, I agree with your second point. Karadur, to allow `std::cout << myObjectPtr;` to run custom code, you need to *overload* `std::ostream &operator<<()`.

Comment: @chris I made some adjustments to the code above

Comment: @chris: I like the fact that `cout << "A string";` works, and it wouldn't without pointers...

Comment: @BenVoigt, True enough. I don't see what else really chains in the waya `char *` does for a string, though. If you want something like that, you might as well put that behaviour in another class.

Answer (score 4):

> I would like to see what a working implementation class would look
>   like

Here you go:

```
#include <iostream>

class Llama
{
private:
  std::string   name_;

public:
  Llama(const std::string &name): name_(name)
  {}

  friend std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Llama *);
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &o, const Llama *llama)
{
  o << llama->name_;
  return o; /* this is important, because it allows chaining */
}


int     main(int, char **)
{
  Llama *llama = new Llama("Meh");

  std::cout << llama << " is the name of my llama" << std::endl;
  return (0);
}
```

What I meant about "chaining":

1. `std::cout << llama` will be executed first. This will returns an `std::ostream` reference: in this case, this reference is `std::cout` itself.
2. Now, we can "replace" `std::cout << llama` by `std::cout`, because of 1.
3. `std::cout << " is the ..."` will be executed. Then `std::cout << std::endl`.

This is why returning the reference to the `std::ostream` is important.

Comment: I am having trouble converting this to my code

I am getting a lot of Error: no operator "<<" matches these operands errors

Comment: could you refer to my EDIT in the above section and let me know if I am placing the coding accurately.. this is occuring on the << in   outs << drive->name_;

Comment: It seems fine. Could you copy/paste the relevant lines from the compilation log? If it's too long, use pastebin.

Comment: [link]http://pastebin.com/kg8d7zfs
[link]http://pastebin.com/TL3uE49B
[link]http://pastebin.com/Qha67b4i
[link]http://pastebin.com/kW19KYsP

All four relevant outputs, flashdrive.h flashdrive.cpp flashdrivER.cpp and the comp log

Comment: Well, I found `cs52::FlashDrive sample; cin >> sample;` and you asked about an overload that would accept pointers. Try `cs52::FlashDrive sample; cin >> &sample;` see if it builds. However doing `cs52::FlashDrive sample; cin >> &sample;` is an **ugly** thing to do.

Comment: Dynamic allocation without a matching deallocation, so that it is reclaimed at process exit, is ok under some circumstances.  Doing so without a comment explaining the intentional leak is never ok, especially not in an answer that others will learn from.